# Historial año academico de alumno

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Estoy realizando un proyecto de uso personal y tengo una duda a la hora de relacionar las tablas en la base de datos.

> El "proyecto" consiste en una pequeña aplicacion que gestionara alumnos y sus incidencias que tengan en el curso actual, dichos alumnos pasaran a un año academico distinto cada curso (de 2017/2018 a 2018/2019) y me gustaria tener un historial para poder ver lo que paso en años anteriores.

Ya tengo diseñada parte de la base de datos y creo que el problema lo tengo en la tabla ALUMNOS, INCIDENCIAS y EXPEDIENTE (une las dos tablas mediante la clave primaria de ALUMNOS e INCIDENCIAS). Que no se si ahora es necesario crear otra tabla más o algun campo, para poder ver su historial en años anteriores.

Lo mismo la solucion es sencilla pero no llego a verla o mi mente no se abstrae lo suficiente. Si pueden echar una mano en aclararme como debo enfocar la relacion de la base datos, estaria muy agradecido.

Gracias, saludos.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario nada más. Declara las tablas tal que incidencia incluya la fecha en la que sucedió y limita el expediente a la relación entre ALUMNOS e INCIDENCIAS:

**ALUMNOS**

id dato1 dato2 datoN

**INCIDENCIAS**

id fecha dato1 dato2 datoN

**EXPEDIENTE**

id_alumno id_incidencia

La consulta en cuestión sería por tanto, para ver las incidencias de Juan de entre 2017 y 2018:

```
SELECT i.* FROM ALUMNOS a, INCIDENCIAS i, EXPEDIENTE e 
WHERE a.id = e.id_alumno AND e.id_incidencia = i.id AND i.fecha BETWEEN 
'1/1/2017' and 
'31/12/2017' AND a.nombre LIKE "Juan";
```

Comment: ¿De esta forma en la vista HTML mediante un SELECT (según la opción elegida) sea la encargada de ir cambiando las fechas en la consulta?

Comment: Sí, un SELECT y jQuery+AJAX es una forma perfectamenre válida de hacerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda y consejos, os iré informando de los avances y posibles dudas que puedan salir por el camino.